# How to find out last run time of shell script?

Tags: scripting, time, last

I am trying to find out at what time the shell script ran last time within the shell script. 
I tried:

```
ls -laru
ls -lart
```

but all these commands give me the last modified time and last accessed time. I am looking for the last time the shell script ran.

Comment: There is no command. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What does the script do ? If it creates certain files can the timestamps on those files be used to deduce the last run time ?

Comment: I don't think this kind of information is standardly recorded on Unix systems.

Comment: If it's run via cron, details of the last run time will be in the cron log.

Comment: @Steve I was trying to run a script and compare its last run time with the file that is created within the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `date` command.
Running date with no options will output the system date and time, as in the following output:

```
date
```

Thu Feb 8 16:47:32 MST 2001

You can save the output of date in a file and within your script check that file for the date. 
To check the last run time within the script, you can check that file:

```
startTime=$(cat time.start)
//code to check the value of last run time goes here
```

`date > time.start //save the time in default format`

There are different formats of date here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

Comment: I tried using date command but it doesn't give me the last run file after I ran the shell script.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and was able to solve my problem:

```
inode=$(find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*error*.log' -printf '%T@ %i\n' | sort -rn | awk '{print $2;exit;}')

newest=$(find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -inum "$inode")
```